# What does lubuntu-defaults-settings actually do?

Tags: lubuntu, settings, default

I know this sounds like a silly, self-explanatory question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere else.

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 and I would like to know what would happen if I run:

```
    sudo apt-get install lubuntu-default-settings
```

Does it just reset everything to how it was when Lubuntu was first installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that would not reset your settings to defualt. Lubuntu comes with this package installed and does not remove it when you change say the screensaver settings or the configuration of lxpanel. Remember because you need sudo to add and remove packages so an child without sudo permissons for say your child changes config would not have this happen to remove it. The most likely result is it will say lubuntu-default-settings is already the most recent release.

Lubuntu-default-settings is really a package to install the default config files for lubuntu. Well as a tester it is important to make sure this is right as updating this package even will not update existing users as they all have config files copied to their home directories.